# Apex button and procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Im trying to create button in Apex which execute given procedure. As input values I gave two date fields called Poczatek and Koniec. The button should execute this procedure on submit. It perfectly works in Oracle, but throw a lot of errors in Apex.

```
set serveroutput on
create or replace procedure KORELACJA(:Poczatek, :Koniec)
IS
miasto VARCHAR(25);
korelacja NUMBER;
cursor c1 is
    SELECT TEMP.nazwa, corr(TEMP.temperatura, WILGOTNOSC.wilg) 
    FROM TEMP INNER JOIN WILGOTNOSC
     on TEMP.nazwa = WILGOTNOSC.nazwa 
     and TEMP.data = WILGOTNOSC.data 
     WHERE TEMP.data between to_date(:Poczatek, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date(:Koniec, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    GROUP BY TEMP.nazwa;
BEGIN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(RPAD('Miasto',10)||RPAD('Korelacja',10));
open c1;
FOR i IN 1..6
LOOP
commit;
fetch c1 into miasto, korelacja;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(RPAD(miasto,10)||RPAD(korelacja,10));
END LOOP;
close c1;
END KORELACJA;
/
```

Errors look like this:

```
1 error has occurred
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5: PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option 
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 6, 
column 11: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMBER" when expecting one of the 
following: := . ( @ % ; ORA-06550: line 9, column 18: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when 
expecting one of the following: , ; for group having intersect minus order start 
union where connect
```

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: miło mi jest zobaczyć polski kod :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to leave the procedure in the database; call it from Apex.

As you said that it works OK, I'm not going to examine the code. Just modify the first line:

```
create or replace procedure KORELACJA(par_Poczatek in date, 
                                      par_Koniec    in date)
is ...
```

Then, in Apex process, call the procedure as

```
korelacja(:p1_poczatek, :p2_koniec);
```

Note that you might need to apply TO_DATE function to those items, using appropriate format mask, such as

```
korelacja(to_date(:p1_poczatek, 'dd.mm.yyyy',
          to_date(:p1_koniec  , 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

---

If you insist on keeping the procedure in Apex' process (I wouldn't recommend it), the you don't need `CREATE PROCEDURE`  but an anonymous PL/SQL block. It won't accept any parameters - use Apex items directly.

```
declare
  miasto    VARCHAR(25);
  korelacja NUMBER;
  cursor ...
    WHERE TEMP.data between to_date(:p1_Poczatek, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ...
begin
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped and procedure works. Right now I would like to redirect the dbms_output to another page in apex. Do you have any tips/suggestion?

Comment: You're welcome. What do you plan to do with the result of procedure's DBMS_OUTPUT? Just to display it? If so, you'd rather create a (classic or interactive) report in Apex, whose source is procedure's cursor's SELECT statement.

Comment: yes, I just want to display the result of executing procedure on another page. What do you mean by: "source is procedure's cursor's SELECT statement"?

Comment: But, the procedure doesn't *compute* anything, it just loops through the cursor and displays some data. As I said: use cursor's SELECT statement as report source in Apex. Oh, yes - I've just noticed: remove COMMIT out of the loop. Also, you can remove it completely; what are you committing? Besides, a SUBMIT button would COMMIT anyway.

Comment: SELECT TEMP.nazwa, corr(TEMP.temperatura, WILGOTNOSC.wilg)
[...]
GROUP BY TEMP.nazwa;
do you mean to use the code above as a report source?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought.

Comment: Hey, I tried exactly the way you described, I mean creating interactive report and putting there the part of code from SELECT (changing date range to :p1_poczatek, :p1_koniec in that statement). But actually it doesn't show corr(TEMP.temperatura, WILGOTNOSC.wilg) only this: TEMP.nazwa. Do you maybe know whats the reason? I was trying to fix it for few hours right now. Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: Did you set corr(...) expression's column alias? For example, name it CORR_RESULT. Make sure its type is something that actually displays on the screen (i.e. is not *hidden*).

Comment: Yes, I gave it an alias, I will try to search for "hidden" then. Is there an issue if I chose TEMP table when creating interactive report and WILGOTNOSC table was not chosen? I was thinking if I'm joining them then TEMP is the one I want

Comment: Of course it matters. If you didn't use WILGOTNOSC table in the FROM clause, what does the CORR call look like? The simplest principle is: write a SELECT statement in SQLPlus (or SQL Developer, or any other tool you use). Once you're satisfied with how it looks like, copy/paste it into Apex report's source.

Comment: Ah okay! thank you, so the statement from above needs to be modified. I will try to do it. Thanks you!

Comment: Oh, but wait, because I started to think about it. I used  FROM TEMP INNER JOIN WILGOTNOSC as it was in the code, but I was thinking about report creation, point 9 on this webpage: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r40/apexirr/apexirrdev/apexirrdev_ll.htm 
I've chosen only TEMP, not WILGOTNOSC. Is this the issue?
SOrry for all the annoying questions, but its all new to me

Comment: Do you really use Apex 4? That wizard creates a report based on a table - you need (as a source) a **SQL query**. I don't have Apex 4 any more and don't remember how it exactly was, but - no problem if you select TEMP table and let the wizard do the job. Once it is done, go to report's source query, delete the one Apex created and paste the one that uses join between two tables. BTW, you probably don't need "report and form", but only "(interactive) report".

Comment: Yes, Apex 4 is the one we use at University... 
I tried as  you described, so selected TEMP and then pasted my code, but the CORR value is not printed, thats where Im stuck

Comment: Hm. Basically, that's a pretty simple task you have. Do you see CORR's header? I mean, is the header displayed, but there's no value in that column, or do you not see absolutely anything related to CORR? If header is there but no value (while you see the value in SQLPlus), are you sure that you're connected to the same user and see the same data as in SQLPlus?

Comment: No, there is no header. Even if I can see it in Report Columns and its not Hidden.

Comment: Manage to fixed it! It was Actions -> Select -> Display in Report!

I was thinking its not hidden, because when I hide other columne then resetting settings shown it back. 

Thanks for all your help : )

Comment: Aha; OK then, I'm glad you fixed it! Congratulations!